# Configure Windows NTP service for Linux clients

Tags: windows, ntp, time-synchronization

I have 100 Linux clients and a Windows Server 2016 in a closed network environment. I would like to have the Ubuntu clients time sync with the Windows Server's date-time. I have done this on internet-open clients but I've not found found how to do this in a **closed environment** with Windows as the NTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Time synchronization as a client is handled in Ubuntu by a systemd task. Check the manual for `timesyncd.conf` but you can set the server list to fetch time from for  `timedatectl` and `timesyncd` in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

Then simply configure your Windows machine with a proper `ntpd` service.